# When to use the Value keyword in C#

Tags: c#

I am using a [custom serializer](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx) in c# in order to serialize/deserialize an object with a dictionary. However during the deserialization the dictionary object was not being set correctly. See code:

```
public DictionarySerializer<String, Point> jointDictionary
    {
        get { return _jointDictionary; }
        set { _jointDictionary = jointDictionary; }
    }
```

The jointDictionary object coming back was empty however in the debugger thread I noticed a "value" object that had the contents of my dictionary. Changing my code to the following fixed my issue:

```
public DictionarySerializer<String, Point> jointDictionary
    {
        get { return _jointDictionary; }
        set { _jointDictionary = value; }
    }
```

I have read about the "value" keyword and understand that it is a reserved word in C# to specify the value that the client it trying to use to set the object. So my question is, why wouldn't the jointDictionary reference work as in my first attempt? And what is the correct usage for the value keyword?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The keyword `value` represents the value which is being passed to the property.  You should always use it within the property setter.

In the case you used `jointDictionary` you were binding to the property getter.  This makes

```
set { _jointDictionary = jointDictionary; }
```

Compiles to

```
set { _jointDictionary = this.jointDictionary; }
```

Which since this accesses the property getter it really becomes

```
set { _jointDictionary = _jointDictionary; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first implementation is recursive.

`_jointDictionary` is set to `jointDictionary`, which calls the getter which returns `_jointDictionary` which has not been set yet.

Thus, the result is blank.

It's as if you did:

`_jointDictionary = _jointDictionary;`

The `value` keyword allows you to access the value being passed into the setter, which is what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
public DictionarySerializer<String, Point> jointDictionary
{
    get { return _jointDictionary; }
    set { _jointDictionary = jointDictionary; }
}
```

Does the following when `set` is called:

1. `jointDictionary` is read via `get`
2. `get` returns `_jointDictionary`
3. `_jointDictionary` is set to what was returned

So the `set` method effectively does nothing, and `_jointDictionary` will remain with the value it started with (in this case, `null`).

Answer (score 0):

If it did work, it would be illogical, as you would be 'essentially' creating a loop situation, where you are attempting to assign a variable to the value of the variable that you are trying to assign.

In short, 'Aliens'.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt was wrong since referencing the property within itself would return the value of the property before the property was set.

So by:

```
set { _jointDictionary = jointDictionary; }
```

you actually did:

```
_jointDictionary = _jointDictionary;
```

because of:

```
get { return _jointDictionary; }
```

Answer (score 0):

if think you of the `get` and `set` methods as any other functions, `value` makes a little more sense.

```
get { return _jointDictionary; } 
set { _jointDictionary = value; }
```

is basicly c# syntactic sugar for:

```
DictionarySerializer<String, Point> get()
{ 
    return _jointDictionary; 
} 

void set( DictionarySerializer<String, Point> value ) 
{ 
    _jointDictionary = value; 
}
```

since the type of the return value in the getter, and the value arg in the setter are declared upfront in the declaration of the property, it is avoiding redundant information.

unless you **need** the private class variable (either for validation or notifications), there's an even simpler syntax of just:

```
DictionarySerializer<String, Point> JointDictionary { get; set; }
```

in this case, the complier is automatically generating the private member and the code for the getter and setter.